# MonoTouch - access to Obj-C Constants

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, constants

Many times I'll read Obj-C code and need the value to one of their constants present in one of the Obj-C header files.

For notifications, I've been able to find them in MonoTouch such as `UIApplication.DidEnterBackgroundNotification`.

Is there a standard way to get such values?  I am needing to lookup `UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration` for an odd reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a `CGFloat`, which MonoTouch maps to a .NET `System.Single` (`float` in C#).

You should be able to use `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn.GetFloat` method to retrieve the *constant* (it could change between versions and should not be embedded like a C# `const`) value at runtime. E.g.

```
IntPtr handle = Dlfcn.dlopen (Constants.UIKitLibrary, 0);
return Dlfcn.GetFloat (handle, "UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration");
```

Comment: I'll try it.  Does `handle` need to be closed within a try-finally block?

Comment: (a) In this case closing should not be an issue since the library is already loaded into memory. (b) `MonoTouch.Constants` is public - it's also very handy to know the version of MonoTouch at runtime :-)